# Undefined operator FUNCTION in form (FUNCTION (QUOTE A)) in nfa compiler

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, nfa

I'm trying to write an epsilon-nfa compiler for regular expression in lisp for a course project. Given this input prompt

`CL prompt> (defparameter nfa-name (nfa-regexp-comp 'reg-exp))`

should return the automata. The best i've came up to is this function:

```
;ALL THE CREATE-NFA FUNCTIONS ARE ALREADY DEFINED LATER IN THE CODE
 (defun nfa-regex-comp (RE)  
  (cond
   ((is-regexp RE)  ; working function returning true if the input is a regexp
    (cond
     ((atom RE) (create-nfa-atom RE))   ; if atom
     ((equal (car RE) 'star) 
          (create-nfa-star (nfa-regex-comp (cadr RE))))  ; if <RE>*
     ((equal (car RE) 'plus) 
          (create-nfa-plus (nfa-regex-comp (cadr RE))))  ; if <RE>+
     ((equal (car RE) 'seq) 
          (create-nfa-seq (map 'list #'nfa-regex-comp (cdr RE))))  ; if <RE1>...<REn>
     ((equal (car RE) 'or) 
          (create-nfa-or (map 'list #'nfa-regex-comp (cdr RE))))))  ; if <RE1>|...|<REn>
     (t nil)))
```

when i load it and try it, input being

`(defparameter basic-nfa-1 (nfa-regexp-comp ’a))` (teacher example)

LispWorks returns this error

`Undefined operator NFA-REGEXP-COMP in form (NFA-REGEXP-COMP (QUOTE A))`

and i can't understand why is it.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You have a typo: `nfa-regexp-comp` instead of `nfa-regex-comp`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I spent literally two hours and I signed in StackOverflow just for this. Guess I'll delete the thread, it adds nothing

Answer (score 4):

IF you use `apropos` you can search for a symbol with a substring:

```
CL-USER 25 > (apropos "NFA")
TYPE::DNFA
NFA-REGEX-COMP (defined)
CREATE-NFA-ATOM
CREATE-NFA-SEQ
CREATE-NFA-PLUS
CREATE-NFA-STAR
CREATE-NFA-OR
```

Above shows that `NFA-REGEX-COMP` is a defined function. I would then look at what you have typed and what the system says exists:

```
CL-USER 26 > (equal 'NFA-REGEX-COMP 'NFA-REGEXP-COMP)
NIL
```

So there must be a difference...

Let's look for the mismatch:

```
CL-USER 27 > (mismatch (symbol-name 'NFA-REGEX-COMP)
                       (symbol-name 'NFA-REGEXP-COMP))
9
```

The mismatch is at character 9:

```
CL-USER 28 > (aref (symbol-name 'NFA-REGEX-COMP) 9)
#\-

CL-USER 29 > (aref (symbol-name 'NFA-REGEXP-COMP) 9)
#\P
```

While we are at it: a few style improvements:

- `car`, `cdr`, `cadr` can be replaced by `first`, `rest`, `second` --> slight readability improvements
- `cond` with many comparisons can be replaced by `case`. `ecase` additionally checks that the item is actually matching in some clause.

Example:

```
(defun nfa-regex-comp (RE)  
  (when (is-regexp RE)         ; working function returning true if the input is a regexp
    (if (atom RE)
        (create-nfa-atom RE)   ; if atom
      (ecase (first RE)
        (star (create-nfa-star (nfa-regex-comp (second RE))))                ; if <RE>*
        (plus (create-nfa-plus (nfa-regex-comp (second RE))))                ; if <RE>+
        (seq  (create-nfa-seq (map 'list #'nfa-regex-comp (rest RE))))       ; if <RE1>...<REn>
        (or   (create-nfa-or  (map 'list #'nfa-regex-comp (rest RE))))))))
```